# How to group values from the same line into a pair?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to write a program that reads a text file which has a data set in the form below and puts every 2 integers per line into a pair:

```
    1    2
    3    4
    5    6
    ... and so on
```

Currently, this part of my main code reads the file line by line and converts the imported strings to integers one number at a time, but I am not sure how I would group 2 integers at a time in each line and put them in a pair. Ultimately, I want to add all the pairs to a single set.

```
    while (getline(fs, line))  {
            istringstream is(line); 
                while(is >> line) {                                             
               int j = atoi(line.c_str());
                cout << "j = " << j << endl;}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help:

```
std::string line;
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> myset;
while (std::getline(fs, line)) {
    std::istringstream is(line);
    int a, b;
    if (is >> a >> b) {
        myset.insert({a, b});
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid data");
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Urcq2m)

To consider `1, 5` as identical as `5, 1`, you may use:

```
struct unordered_pair_comp
{
    bool operator () (const std::pair<int, int>& lhs, const std::pair<int, int>& rhs) const
    {
        return std::minmax(lhs.first, lhs.second) < std::minmax(rhs.first, rhs.second);
    }
};
```

and so your `myset` becomes `std::set<std::pair<int, int>, unordered_pair_comp> myset;`

[Live example](https://ideone.com/sO3ADS)

Comment: That helped, thanks a lot! I also want to make sure, duplicates are not allowed into the set, and by duplicates I mean something like .. 1   5 and 5   1. How would I check for that?

Comment: I added your method to my code but I get a compilation error, it says "minmax was not declared in this scope". Not sure what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @sparta93: `std::minmax` is in `<algorithm>`, and requires C++11.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `std::pair`, like this:

```
istringstream is(line); 
pair<int, int> p;
is >> p.first;
is >> p.second;
cout << p.first << "  " << p.second;
```

In next step you could use `std::set<std::pair<int, int> >` to acheive your goal of putting the pairs into single set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::ifstream ifs{ "yourfile.txt" };
// read line by line
std::string line;
while(std::getline(ifs, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss{ line }; // make a stream on the line
    auto values = std::make_pair<int, int>(0, 0);
    if(iss >> values.first >> values.second) { // check stream state 
                                               // after reading two ints
                                               // (this skips spaces)
        std::cout << "a=" << values.first << ", b=" << values.second << "\n";
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error{ "bad data" };
    }

    // at this point, you have read a valid pair of ints into "values"
}
```

See the code comments for explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Use pair available in 'utility'  header, following is the sample code for the same.

```
while (getline(fs, line))  
{
     stringstream is;
     is<<test;
     int i, j;
     is>>i;
     is>>j;
     pair<int, int> pr(i,j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont make the imported strings into integers. Read the two strings from one line and concatenate them. Then make them integers. Like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;    

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream fs("input.txt");
    while (getline(fs, line))
    {
        istringstream is(line);
        string num1, num2;

        while (is >> num1 >> num2)
        {
            num1 += num2;
            int j = stoi(num1);
            cout << "j = " << j << endl;
        }
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for your purposes.

```
while (getline(fs, line)) 
{
    istringstream is(line); 
    int i, j;
    is >> i >> j;
    std::pair<int,int> my_pair = std::make_pair (i, j);
}
```