# Sorting and deleting duplicates not working for large vectors

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to read numerical data (in pairs) from a text file, remove the duplicates and then tell me the size of the vector before moving on to other things. I tested the code below and it works with files that have about 10-20 lines of data, however when I try it on larger data sets (over 100,000 lines of numerical data), there is no output when I try to cout the size(); of the vector. Not sure what the problem is.

```
while( getline( fs1, instrng ) ) {

    istringstream s1(instrng);
    int a, b;
    s1 >> a >> b;
    pair<int,int> pair1 = make_pair(a,b);
    vec1.push_back( pair1 );

    sort( vec1.begin(), myvec1.end() );
    myvec.erase(unique(myvec.begin(),myvec.end()), myvec.end());
```

Comment: So are you on a mission to solve [each](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25820365/1870232) and [every](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25820586/1870232) scenario of this problem using SO ?

Comment: Use `std::set` instead.

Comment: I have to use a vector for this program @Jarod42

Comment: So look at `std::lower_bound` and `std::vector::insert`. You won't have to re-sort the vector every time, just insert element to the right place (if not already present).

Comment: Seeing your exact similar post looks like you suffer from [_X-Y_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) problem. You need to take [advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820586/how-to-remove-specific-pairs-from-a-vector#comment40393538_25820586) from people, given in those comments, also programming includes _debugging_ skills something simply doesn't go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context the use of `std::sort()` and `std::unique()` is working. The problem is a performance issue. You need to do one of two things:

1. You wait long enough to give the implementation a chance to do a lot of sorting.
2. You move the use of `std::sort()`, `std::unique()`, and `std::vector<...>::erase()` out of the loop.

Put differently: you managed to create a `O(n * n * log n)` implementation for something which should be `O(n * log n)` where `n` is the number of elements.

BTW, you should *always* verify that input was successful: you failed to check that reading the two integers on the line was successful. Personally, I would just read the integers from the original stream and not use `std::istringstream` as creation and/or set up of these streams is also adding unnecessary costs. This cost is, admittedly, a lot less than sorting for each element.

Comment: Just for the records because it looks like abeginners question: He could also use std::lower_bound to find the position to insert the element and check if the element is already in the vector inside the loop. This may save memory, although I doubt that this will be an issue with pairs of integers since you can have ~130,000 pairs in 1MB of memory. And inserting at random positions can destroy performance because the loop is then O(n^2).